# Ezsearch for Umbraco wont find results below 3 characters

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, umbraco

I can't figure out why Ezsearch (Umbraco package) can't find results below 3 characters.

Search for xx-x gives a result
Search for xxx wont give any results

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with umbraco 7.5. Is not yet resolved.